# Extract email from filename using regex

Tags: php, regex

I have filenames in this format:
`SCANNERID_00001SCAN_28-11-2013_email_X_gmail.com_LEFT.zip`

another example

`SCANNERID_99999SCAN_33-03-2015_mymail_X_hotmail.com_RIGHT.zip`

the `@` sign has been replaced with an `_X_`. The side (at the end of the filename, in this case `LEFT`) is variable; either `LEFT` or `RIGHT`.

the date is obviously variable and is not necessarily the current date.

I want to extract `email@gmail.com` or `mymail@hotmail.com` using regexp in PHP.

Comment: Can you give us more sample inputs/outputs?

Comment: Updated my initial question with more examples

Answer (score 3):

```
preg_replace("/SCANNERID_.+_\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,4}_(.+)_X_(.+)_(LEFT|RIGHT).zip/", "$1@$2", $input_lines);
```